Win 10 DNLA clients, folders showing but not files
Win 10 DNLA clients, folders showing but not files.
I replaced the HDD (now E drive in the old DVD slot) with an SSD (now C drive). The E drive continues to show folders and files on my tv but the new C drive only shows folders.
If I use a Plex server on the pc, the tv can see both folders and files from the C drive.
The C drive folders and files are showing in windows explorer and wmp.
I've tried all the sharing, security, indexing and wmp settings and icacls (icacls "C:\my folder" /grant Everyone:M) command with no sucess.
Even though I have work arounds I would really like to know how to get the windows server to show the files from the new C drive.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
